# Duplicate channels and roles are created when the discord bot enters a server

Tags: amazon-ec2, discord, discord.js

I want to create a channel and two roles when a discord bot enters a new server. I run the following code on `guildCreate` event.

I am first checking if the channel or roles exist. If not, then create them, but instead of one 3 roles are getting created. I am unable to replicate the problem by running the bot locally.

The discord bot is running on AWS EC2 instance which has 2 CPUs and the express server is using forking to create a fork for each CPU.

Below is the relevant code:

```
import {
  ChannelType,
  Client,
  Colors,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  OverwriteType,
  PermissionsBitField,
} from "discord.js";

import {
  InteractionResponseFlags,
  InteractionResponseType,
} from "discord-interactions";

const debounce = (func, wait) => {
  let timeout;

  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, args), wait);
  };
};

const handleGuildCreate = async (guild) => {
  logger.info(`Joined new guild: ${guild.id}`);
  console.log(`Joined new guild: ${guild.id}`);
  try {
    const roleExist = !guild.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === BOT_ROLE_ADMIN);
    console.log("roleExist 1 Admin Role", roleExist);
    if (roleExist){
      console.log("Creating Admin Role");
      await guild.roles.create({
        name: BOT_ROLE_ADMIN,
        color: Colors.Blue,
        reason: `${BOT_NAME} needs an administrative role that can fetch wallet addresses`,
      });
      console.log("Admin Role Created");
    }
    const roleExist2 = !guild.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === BOT_ROLE_VERIFIED);
    console.log("roleExist 2 Member Role", roleExist2);
    if (roleExist2){
      console.log("Creating Member Role");
      await guild.roles.create({
        name: BOT_ROLE_VERIFIED,
        color: Colors.Red,
        reason: `${BOT_NAME} needs an administrative role that can gate tokens`,
      });
      console.log("Member Role Created");
    }
    const channelExist = !guild.channels.cache.some(
      (channel) => channel.name === BOT_ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL
    );
    console.log("channelExist", channelExist);
    if (channelExist) {
      const adminRole = guild.roles.cache.find(
        (role) => role.name === BOT_ROLE_ADMIN
      );
      const everyoneRole = guild.roles.everyone;
      console.log("Creating Channel");
      await guild.channels.create({
        name: BOT_ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL,
        type: ChannelType.GuildText,
        permissionOverwrites: [
          {
            type: OverwriteType.Role,
            id: everyoneRole.id,
            deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel],
          },
          {
            type: OverwriteType.Role,
            id: adminRole.id,
            allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel],
          },
        ],
      });
      console.log("Channel Created");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
  }
};

const debouncedGuildCreate = debounce(handleGuildCreate, 2000);

bot.on("guildCreate", debouncedGuildCreate);
```

AWS CloudWatch logs:

```
2023-11-07T11:15:05.626-08:00   The number of CPUs is 2
2023-11-07T11:15:05.626-08:00   Master 1 is running
2023-11-07T11:15:08.535-08:00   Radical Discord Bot is listening at http://localhost:80
2023-11-07T11:15:08.677-08:00   Radical Discord Bot is listening at http://localhost:80
2023-11-07T12:07:45.980-08:00   info: Joined new guild: 1171541195919466626 {"service":"rs-server-log"}
2023-11-07T12:07:45.980-08:00   Joined new guild: 1171541195919466626
2023-11-07T12:07:45.982-08:00   roleExist 1 Admin Role false
2023-11-07T12:07:45.982-08:00   roleExist 2 Member Role false
2023-11-07T12:07:45.982-08:00   channelExist false
2023-11-07T12:07:46.015-08:00   info: Joined new guild: 1171541195919466626 {"service":"rs-server-log"}
2023-11-07T12:07:46.015-08:00   Joined new guild: 1171541195919466626
2023-11-07T12:07:46.015-08:00   roleExist 1 Admin Role false
2023-11-07T12:07:46.015-08:00   roleExist 2 Member Role false
2023-11-07T12:07:46.015-08:00   channelExist false
2023-11-07T12:07:46.016-08:00   info: Joined new guild: 1171541195919466626 {"service":"rs-server-log"}
2023-11-07T12:07:46.016-08:00   Joined new guild: 1171541195919466626
2023-11-07T12:07:46.018-08:00   roleExist 1 Admin Role false
2023-11-07T12:07:46.018-08:00   roleExist 2 Member Role false
2023-11-07T12:07:46.018-08:00   channelExist false
```

I tried adding the debounce function to prevent multiple calls for being fired together in case they all were checking if the channel or role existed very close to one another.